# What is the motivation for the rule and lore changes in 7th Sea 2e?

Tags: history-of-gaming, game-design, 7th-sea, 7th-sea-2e

When I first heard about the second edition for 7th Sea, I thought it would be a small update to the first one - like offering searchable .pdfs, having a nicer layout and better pictures in the books, eliminating typos and integrating some of the rule corrections. However, when I had a first look into the new book, it seemed like a lot of mechanics and lore has changed - new wizard heritages, different hero creation, new things like danger points and so on.

I'm surprised by the updates being as significant as they are, since the game was discontinued for many years with no new printings or material at all.

What was the motivation behind creating a second edition that also changed so much?

Comment: Major rule changes across editions is normal in RPGs (Compare D&D 4e and 5e for example). Is it possible that you mixed up the words *edition* with *printing*, which is *Edition* or *Auflage* in German?

Comment: @MrLemon that might be a reason for my expectation being that different. However, I still wonder what might be the motivation to conduct these changes after that many years. If that is similar to other game systems, so be it.

Comment: An answer incorporating speculation or designer commentary on each change may be overwhelming with the release of a new edition. Is there a particular change that really concerns you that you can focus on? (Then, when you find another, you can pose an additional question.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, I think I wonder more about the general decision to do a second edition changing that much. It´s not obvious to me, considering that the game has been discontinued for so much time (no new printings of the books, no new material and so on...)

Comment: I've edited your question to try to express what you've said here in comments. It helps us figure out what's going on here - like, what went through my head was "it's a new edition, why *wouldn't* it have lots of improvements, isn't that normal, why are you asking about this?". Your explanation helps us understand what's got you confused, which helps us handle this question & its answers better. If you'd like to revise my changes (e.g. to put them in your own voice rather than mine), go right ahead.

Comment: @doppelgreener Thank you for the edit, that is indeed a lot better!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Straight from the [Kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/johnwickpresents/7th-sea-second-edition/description):

> *7th Sea: Second Edition* gives me a chance to not only bring the game back to all its devoted fans, but also to give it a new engine with plenty of chrome. Since 1999, we’ve made a lot of progress in the roleplaying game industry. We have new design tools, new publishing options, and new ideas about what makes a roleplaying game work. I want to take advantage of all that new stuff and help *7th Sea* become the game that I always wanted it to be: fast, fun, furious action that tells the stories of great heroes facing impossible odds amidst global politics.

In addition, John Wick did an interview on Talking Tabletop ([part 1](http://oneshotpodcast.com/podcasts/talking-with-john-wick/) and [part 2](http://oneshotpodcast.com/podcasts/28-john-wick/)) where he discussed why he was doing what he was doing, and it boiled down to "this time, I'm doing *my* vision of Théah."

It's been a while since I listened to it (they were released in March 2016) but in a nutshell at AEG he may have conceived *7th Sea*, but there was an entire team working on it, and the buck didn't stop with him. This time it does. Not that AEG didn't treat him or *7th Sea* well, but he is ready to mold the world into his original vision.

As to 'why now?' Because he [recently got the rights to it](http://www.alderac.com/blog/2015/11/03/a-return-to-7th-sea/).

Comment: http://www.tabletopgamingnews.com/aeg-to-sell-back-7th-sea-game-license-to-john-wick-presents/ might be a relevent edition for the "why now?" part of the question that the OP added to the comments.

Comment: Ak. "Addition".

Answer (score 8):

When JWP got the rights back there was a long discussion about how much we should diverge from 1st Edition; both in mechanics and lore. That's to say there are a lot of reasons for going the direction we did. For example, 1st Edition still exists. JWP offers PDF support for the old game and has no plans on discontinuing that. Since we're still treating 1st Edition like a viable option, we decided to deliver a new experience for our fans.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I was honestly about to ask you to cite sources, but, uhhh... you seem to *be* about authoritative as a source gets. Glad to have you on the site!

Comment: Haha. Thanks! I stumbled over here and figured I could throw a few answers down for people. :D